# Как реализовать сохранение пользователем разметки XAML?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Всем привет!

Проект WPF.

Собственно, хочу узнать как лучше(и можно ли вообще) такое реализовать. Т.е, например, пользователь по нажатию кнопки добавляет текстовое поле и при следующем запуске программы это поле уже будет в окне.

Были мысли в сторону того, чтобы сохранять разметку в файл xml, а потом подставлять ее в разметку xaml, но не нашел как.

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Вы не в том направлении думаете. В WPF проекте данные и UI должны быть отдельны друг от друга. То есть, к примеру у вас есть класс с простыми свойствами, в XAML вы привязываете нужные контролы к этим свойствам, все, у вас данные в классе, а UI в XAML. В таком случае вам достаточно сохранить лишь класс (десериализовать в JSON, например при закрытии) и при последующих загрузках восстанавливать все данные. Еще раз заметьте, я не говорю про контролы, они автоматически должны подстраиваться под классы!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XAML разметка - это нечно статичное, то что вы создаете при реализации приложения. Она не изменяется во время его работы. Конечно, техническая возможность распарсить XAML и загрузить из него интерфейс есть, но в этом нет никакого практического смысла, к тому же это не просто.

*Но если вам интересно, как именно загружается XAML разметка, поставьте курсор на `InitializeComponent()` и нажмите F12, увидите исходный код загрузчика окна.*

Если вам нужна куча текстбоксов, а данные для текстбокса - это строка, то вам нужна коллекция строк. Есть в дотнете особая коллекция `ObservableCollection`, состав которой интерфейс умеет автоматически отслеживать. То есть вы создаете в ней элемент, и интерфейс тут же реагирует на эти изменения. И есть простой контрол, который умеет работать с такими коллекциями - `ItemsControl`. Чтобы их подружить вместе, нужно выполнить привязку данных коллекции к этому контролу. За это отвечает `Binding`.

Привязка возможна только к публичным свойствам. Давайте создадим такое свойство, например прямо в классе `MainWindow`.

```cs
public ObservableCollection<string> Items { get; } = new ObservableCollection<string>();
```

Далее в XAML разметке нужно реализовать вот такую конструкцию

```xml
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBox Text="{Binding}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

В таком виде работать не будет, а чтобы заработало, надо в конструкторе окна назначить `DataContext`, то есть указать место, где `Binding` должен искать данные.

```cs
InitializeComponent();
DataContext = this;
```

Вот теперь все работает. Например если вы захотите добавить элемент, надо просто сделать вот так.

```cs
Items.Add(string.Empty);
```

И тут же появится текстбокс.

Чтобы сохранить данные, можно использовать сериализацию коллекции, например в JSON.

```cs
File.WriteAllText("file.json", JsonSerializer.Serialize(Items));
```

А вот чтобы загрузить, есть нюанс, без реализации `INotifyPropertyChanged` (это отдельная история, но копать вам надо именно туда), присваивание `Items` можно делать только в конструкторе, в противном случае привязка будет разорвана, и интерфейс просто потеряет данные. Поэтому придется добавлять элементы, а не пересоздавать коллекцию.

```
Items.Clear();
string[] items = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<string[]>(File.ReadAllText("file.json"));
foreach (string item in items)
{
    Items.Add(item);
}
```

Если это надо делать при загрузке приложения, то лучше этот код разместить в обработчике события `Window.Loaded`. Не пишите в конструкторе окна свой код, ну кроме того что я выше про `DataContext` указал.

Это очень сильно упрощенный пример, чтобы двигаться дальше, вам нужно научиться создавать модели данных (классы для данных) и познакомиться с `INotifyPropertyChanged`. А чтобы эти все знания научиться правильно применять - изучите шаблон проектирования MVVM.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Теперь вижу, что придется пока отложить проект, т.к для моей задумки мне не хватит опыта. Задумка была в том, чтобы пользователь мог сам для себя настроить модель данных, которая будет использоваться в проекте. К примеру, пользователь хочет сделать библиотеку своих книг, и он делает модель данных Книга, в которой свой набор полей(Автор, год, описание, картинка обложки и т.д). Для хранилища рецептов был бы свой набор полей и все в таком духе.

Comment: @pavel05456 ну для этого вам надо познакомиться с интерфейсами и `DataTemplate`, а так же понадобится динамическая десереализация, в целом, при наличии опыта, в этом нет ничего космически сложного. В любом случае, парсить XAML для этого не потребуется. :)